# If I have a python program running, can I edit the .py file that it is running from?

Tags: python

If I have a long running process that is running from file.py, can I edit file.py while it is running and run it again, starting a new process and not affect the already running process?

Comment: yes, you can do that.

Comment: make sure you have backed it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Python is not constantly reading the file, the file is only interpreted once per run. The current instance that is already running will not be affected by changes in the script.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That is what I thought but could not confirm

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

When you are running the first process, the unmodified code is loaded into memory,like a copy in memory. When you edit the running code, it makes another copy into memory, you won't change the original one.

And even though you click save, it won't make any change to the code in the memory that the first process is using.

But as you say, your program is very long. If you change a package the program hasn't used, it may cause the problem, coz the import part is loaded when the program execute the `import` part.